# Excel Count and Multiply cells between sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 sheets, Sheet 1 and Sheet 2.

In Sheet 1 is a list of Vacancies in one cell and next to it is the Name of the person who has those Vacancies.

In Sheet 2 I am trying to find the TOTAL amount of Vacancies that each person listed has using a Formula

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!B:B,A2)
```

The only problem is that it needs to count in Sheet 1 how many vacancies a specific person has.

eg: it shows John has 3 vacancies when he should have 11.

[image]

[image]

Added a SUMIF attempt

[image]

Comment: `SUMIF()` is your friend =)

Comment: @JvdV that just gives me 0

Comment: Do you have string type data that just looks like numeric data? If so, that would explain the `0`

Comment: please mock up an example of the data and expected output.

Comment: @ScottCraner  I have added images to show the data

Comment: @JvdV I have added images to show you the Sheets

Comment: Please include your attempt at `SUMIF()`. Are you using Google-Sheets or Excel btw?

Comment: @JvdV Google Sheets and the result of `=SUMIF(Sheet1!B:B,A2)` is 0

Comment: your sumif would be: `=SUMIF(Sheet1!B:B,A2,Sheet1!A:A)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you should use `SUMIF()` instead of `COUNTIF()` as per the comments above, though since you are not using Excel but Google Spreadsheets, this opens up other options (note, the two look alike but are actually very different).

You could try utilize `QUERY()`:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=QUERY(A1:B,"Select B, Sum(A) where A is not null group by B label Sum(A) 'Total Vacancies'")
```

Comment: You adjust the reference of `A1:B` to the appropriate range of the sheet you refering to @ngDough